# Substitute widget of QDockWidget without deletion of previous

Tags: c++, qt

I want to substitute widget (QWidget*) of QDockWidget*, but call to [setWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#setWidget), deletes previous widget. How to prevent this deletion?

```
QDockWidget* dw = new QDockWidget;
QWidget* tw1 = new TestWidget;
QWidget* tw2 = new TestWidget;
dw->setWidget(tw1);
dw->setWidget(tw2); // tw1 deleted here
delete dw;
// I want to use tw1 here, but it died
```

TestWidget is just a test to check moment of deletion:

```
class TestWidget : public QWidget {
public:
    TestWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        cout << "TestWidget() " << this << endl;
    }
    ~TestWidget() override {
        cout << "~TestWidget() " << this << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. All widgets get destroyed with the `delete dw;` call, just like they should.

Comment: @SteakOverflow I've added additional comment at the end of first code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QDockWidget* dw = new QDockWidget;
QWidget* tw1 = new TestWidget;
QWidget* tw2 = new TestWidget;
dw->setWidget(tw1);
dw->setWidget(tw2);
tw1->setParent(0);
delete dw; // dw and tw2 deleted here, but not tw1
```